# "ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree" when setting up a new project using wdio-v7

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to set up a new project using `wdio-v7`,
firstly I ran `npm init -y`
then `npm install @wdio/cli --save-dev`
and after running `npx wdio config -y` I receive this:

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! While resolving: example-test@1.0.0
    npm ERR! Found: @wdio/cli@7.0.5
    npm ERR! node_modules/@wdio/cli
    npm ERR!   dev @wdio/cli@"^7.0.5" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer @wdio/cli@"^6.0.0" from wdio-chromedriver-service@6.0.4
    npm ERR! node_modules/wdio-chromedriver-service
    npm ERR!   dev wdio-chromedriver-service@"*" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR! 
    
    Initialize WebdriverIO and setup configuration in your current project.
    
    Documentation: https://webdriver.io
    @wdio/cli (v7.0.5)
```

I tried using `--force, or --legacy-peer-deps` but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

That is weird, looks like `npx wdio config -y`is trying to install older version of chrome driver service.

Try to manually install chromedriver service or update the version in package.json

```
"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0"
```

Make sure you have the min requirements by webdriverio

https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted#system-requirements

> Install at least v12.16.1 or higher as this is the oldest active LTS
> version Only releases that are or will become an LTS release are
> officially supported

Comment: Today I tried `npx wdio config -y` again and it worked. It installed the latest version of `wdio-chromedriver-service`